# Passing more then 10 arguments to gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

In the gnuplot 5.2 manual is well explained that it is possible to use string variables ARG0, ARG1, ..., ARG9 and an integer variable ARGC to pass variables to the scripts.
For example if I execute

```
gnuplot -persist -c "script1.gp" "sin(x)" 1.23 "This is a plot title"

ARG0 holds "script1.gp"
ARG1 holds the string "sin(x)"
ARG2 holds the string "1.23"
ARG3 holds the string "This is a plot title"
ARGC is 3
```

Is there a way to pass more then 10 arguments to a gnuplot script, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two files you could use something like this.

In this example, the first script (`send.plt`) send the "arguments", as a single string, to second script.

```
Arg2Sent = "This is a long string send to another script as a single argument"
call "receive.plt" sprintf("%s", Arg2Sent)
```

The second script (`receive.plt`) contain:

```
array Arg[words(ARG1)]

do for [i=1:|Arg|]{
    Arg[i] = word(ARG1, i)
    print sprintf("Arg[%2g]: %s", i, Arg[i])
}
```

The output

```
Arg[ 1]: This
Arg[ 2]: is
Arg[ 3]: a
Arg[ 4]: long
Arg[ 5]: string
Arg[ 6]: send
Arg[ 7]: to
Arg[ 8]: another
Arg[ 9]: script
Arg[10]: as
Arg[11]: a
Arg[12]: single
Arg[13]: argument
```

Another example, this time using numbers.

```
Arg2Sent = "0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765"
call "receive.plt" sprintf("%s", Arg2Sent)
```

The output

```
Arg[ 2]: 1
Arg[ 3]: 1
Arg[ 4]: 2
Arg[ 5]: 3
Arg[ 6]: 5
Arg[ 7]: 8
Arg[ 8]: 13
Arg[ 9]: 21
Arg[10]: 34
Arg[11]: 55
Arg[12]: 89
Arg[13]: 144
Arg[14]: 233
Arg[15]: 377
Arg[16]: 610
Arg[17]: 987
Arg[18]: 1597
Arg[19]: 2584
Arg[20]: 4181
Arg[21]: 6765
```

A long example

```
Arg2Sent = "'first filename with spaces.txt' \
'second filename with spaces.txt' \
'third filename with spaces.txt' \
'fourth filename with spaces.txt' \
'fifth filename with spaces.txt' \
'sixth filename with spaces.txt' \
'seventh filename with spaces.txt' \
'eighth filename with spaces.txt' \
'ninth filename with spaces.txt' \
'tenth  filename with spaces.txt' \
'eleventh filename with spaces.txt' \
'twelfth filename with spaces.txt' \
'thirteenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'fourteenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'fifteenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'sixteenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'seventeenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'eighteenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'nineteenth filename with spaces.txt' \
'twentieth filename with spaces.txt'"

call "receive.plt" sprintf("%s", Arg2Sent)
```

The output

```
Arg[ 1]: first filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 2]: second filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 3]: third filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 4]: fourth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 5]: fifth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 6]: sixth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 7]: seventh filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 8]: eighth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[ 9]: ninth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[10]: tenth  filename with spaces.txt
Arg[11]: eleventh filename with spaces.txt
Arg[12]: twelfth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[13]: thirteenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[14]: fourteenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[15]: fifteenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[16]: sixteenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[17]: seventeenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[18]: eighteenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[19]: nineteenth filename with spaces.txt
Arg[20]: twentieth filename with spaces.txt
```

One last example

```
Arg2Sent = "data.dat 1 2 'lp pt 6' 'pi -1' blue 'A randon example'"

call "receive.plt" sprintf("%s", Arg2Sent)
```

The `receive.plt` contain

```
array Arg[words(ARG1)]

do for [i=1:|Arg|]{
    Arg[i] = word(ARG1, i)
}

filename     = sprintf("%s", Arg[1])
firstcolumn  = int(Arg[2])
secondcolumn = int(Arg[3])
plottype     = sprintf("%s", Arg[4])
pointstyle   = sprintf("%s", Arg[5])
color        = sprintf("'%s'", Arg[6])
title        = sprintf("%s", Arg[7])

plot filename u firstcolumn:secondcolumn w @plottype @pointstyle lc @color t title
```

The output

[image: graph output]

Answer (score 0):

You have different options for the command line, check `help command line options` and `help call`.

```
gnuplot -p -e "<gnuplot command 1; command 2; command 3;>"
```

With this, you can basically enter all your gnuplot commands separated by `;` in a single line.
However, as I understand your question you have a template script where you just want to set some parameters (in your case more than 10) from the command line.

```
gnuplot -p -c "script.gp" "sin(x)" 1.23 "This is a plot title"
```

With this you have a limit of 9 arguments.

But you can pass more than 10 parameters. Simply, call gnuplot with a long `ARG1`, i.e. settings for your variables, and make a macro call `@ARG1` in your script (check `help macros`).

**Script:** `SO60456607.gp`

Note that none of the variables or functions are defined in this template script.

```
### more than 10 "command line arguments"
reset session

@ARG1

plot a*f(x)+b w l lc rgb myColor1 ti myTitle1, \
     c*g(x)+d w l lc rgb myColor2 ti myTitle2, \
     e*g(x)+f w l lc rgb myColor3 ti myTitle3
pause -1
### end of script
```

NB: I haven't yet understood why I have to add `pause -1`. Otherwise the gnuplot window will close immediately although I used the option `-p` for persist.

**Command line:** (tested with Win10)

```
gnuplot -p -c "SO60456607.gp" "a=1; f(x)=sin(x); b=1; myColor1='red'; myTitle1='Test1'; c=2; g(x)=cos(x); d=2; myColor2='green'; myTitle2='Test2'; e=3; h(x)=-sin(x); f=3; myColor3='blue'; myTitle3='Test3';"
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

It is actually mentioned in `help command line options`, you can also do:

> `gnuplot -e "a=2; s='file.png'" input.gpl`

So, you could skip the `@ARG1` in the script above and the command line would become:

**Command line:**

```
gnuplot -p -e "a=1; f(x)=sin(x); b=1; myColor1='red'; myTitle1='Test1'; c=2; g(x)=cos(x); d=2; myColor2='green'; myTitle2='Test2'; e=3; h(x)=-sin(x); f=3; myColor3='blue'; myTitle3='Test3';" "SO60456607.gp"
```

However, then apparently, you cannot do a `reset session` at the beginning of the script because all variables will be deleted (i.e. become undefined).

**Script:** `SO60456607.gp`

```
### more than 10 arguments

plot a*f(x)+b w l lc rgb myColor1 ti myTitle1, \
     c*g(x)+d w l lc rgb myColor2 ti myTitle2, \
     e*g(x)+f w l lc rgb myColor3 ti myTitle3
### end of script
```